# Deploying Symfony2 Application on Heroku

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy symfony2 application on heroku and I keep getting this error:

```
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Resolved composer.lock requirement for PHP >=5.3.3 to version 5.6.2.
-----> Installing system packages...
       - PHP 5.6.2
       - Apache 2.4.10
       - Nginx 1.6.0
-----> Installing PHP extensions...
       - zend-opcache (automatic; bundled, using 'ext-zend-opcache.ini')
-----> Installing dependencies...
       Composer version 1.0-dev (ffffab37a294f3383c812d0329623f0a4ba45387) 2014-11-05 06:04:18
       Loading composer repositories with package information
       Installing dependencies from lock file
       Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
         - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0)
           Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.2.1)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/cache (v1.3.1)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/collections (v1.2)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/common (v2.4.2)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/data-fixtures (dev-master ac36ccc)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing twig/twig (v1.16.2)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing symfony/symfony (v2.5.6)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing jdorn/sql-formatter (v1.2.17)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.4.3)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (v1.2.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle (dev-master 9a5b528)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.4.6)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (v2.1.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing knplabs/knp-components (1.3.1)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle (2.4.1)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing knplabs/knp-snappy (0.2.1)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle (dev-master 4e5a2cf)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing sensiolabs/security-checker (v2.0.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing sensio/distribution-bundle (v3.0.8)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v3.0.2)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing kriswallsmith/assetic (v1.2.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing symfony/assetic-bundle (v2.5.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing monolog/monolog (1.11.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing symfony/monolog-bundle (v2.6.1)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.3.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 15%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 35%    Downloading: 40%    Downloading: 45%    Downloading: 50%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 65%    Downloading: 70%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 80%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 95%    Downloading: 100%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.3.7)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 5%    Downloading: 25%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 55%    Downloading: 60%    Downloading: 85%    Downloading: 90%    Downloading: 100%

     - Installing twig/extensions (v1.2.0)
       Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 0%               Downloading: 10%    Downloading: 20%    Downloading: 30%    Downloading: 75%    Downloading: 100%

   Generating optimized autoload files
   Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
   PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle' not found in /tmp/build_634a4dfca497b3cefc3e87e3c0f3c462/app/AppKernel.php on line 30
   Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception
```

[RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]

!     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app`enter code here`

Comment: before you deploy, make sure you do a composer update to ensure that all dependencies are met.  This will update your composer.lock file. Give it a shot.

Comment: I did, but I keep getting that error

Comment: in your composer.json, do you have the following? `"sensio/generator-bundle" : "2.3.*",` (the version may be different, I use Symfony 2.3)

Comment: yes I do have that line

Comment: that's interesting, because based on your output it doesn't look like that bundle is being downloaded.  you can always try deleting your vendors, clear cache, and do a composer update again (locally) and then deploy again.

Comment: thnks but I have ended up deplying somewhere else. that prblems pissed me off and I could not solve it. thnks

Answer (score 3):

Heroku runs a `composer install --no-dev` upon push, so no development packages get installed.

That means `sensio/generator-bundle` must be listed in `require`, not `require-dev`, in `composer.json` (run `composer update` afterwards to re-generate `composer.lock` as well and commit both).

Also make sure in `AppKernel.php` that the bundle is registered outside the `if()` block that only runs in dev and test envs.

Answer (score 2):

There is confusion between `dev` & `prod` mode. Composer is running as `prod` mode (e.g. `--no-dev`), but your app is trying to run as `dev` mode.

Set the `ENV` var in Heroku:

```
SYMFONY_ENV=prod
```